# Use Fuerte and Hydro

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, ros-hydro, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to send a message in one computer using ROS FUERTE and listen to in a another computer using ROS HYDRO?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89851/use-fuerte-and-hydro/) by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2013-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is even possible to have some nodes running in a fuerte environment and some in a hydro environment on the same computer, provided you properly setup environments in different terminals or screens. Note that message formats have to be the same across ROS versions for this to work, though.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-11**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher thanks im new in ROS so i have some questions, if i just installed ROS fuerte on my computer and want to install now hydro what should i do to make this cross messaging work?  What important environment setups do i have to change or be careful to make this work? Thanks for the responce

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-10-11**:
Typically, you add some a setup script to your .bashrc file as described here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment You switch between ros versions by simply changing what is stated in your .bashrc file. Note that it is always read when you open a new terminal.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-11**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher so if I start the first terminal with fuerte then change the bashrc  open another terminal this new one will be using hydro?  Does it matter with which one i run roscore?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2013-10-13**:
Yes, that's the  quickest way of doing it. You could also create some scripts for quickly switching on the command line. I always use the roscore of the newer ros version, but both variants should work I think.

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-10-14**:
@Stefan Kohlbrecher im trying to install hydro now but im unale to do it due to this error? any ideas how to fix it?'
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-hydro-desktop-full : Depends: ros-hydro-desktop but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-hydro-mobile but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-hydro-perception but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-hydro-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-08-29**:
Add the sources correctly.

Also, @Stefan Kohlbrecher, is there any recommended practice for splitting nodes between hydro and fuerte?

Thank you.

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2014-08-30**:
You´ll want to have two different workspaces for the packages belonging to the different ROS distros and then you only have to take care to only source the corresponding setup files correctly (especially to not mix hydro and fuerte ROS_PACKAGE_PATH etc.).